# How to setup database service container in github workflow CI/CD?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a laravel app and a working Postgis container. Im trying to setup a CI to my project using github workflow beta. my workflow fails when it tries to access the database. For local environment i am setting my database host with my container name `canie-db`. But in my github workflow i am not able to find my database host by my container name. Im getting this error when it tries to run my tests:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not
>   translate host name "canie-db" to address: Temporary failure in name
>   resolution

This is my `.github/workflows/ci.yml`

```
name: CanieCICD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - stage
      - ci/cd-patch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - stage
      - ci/cd-patch

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    services:
      canie-db:
        image: mdillon/postgis:10
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: canie-db
          POSTGRES_USER: iabs_user
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: p@ssw0rd

    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Use Node.js 12.x
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: 12.x

    - name: Install composer dependencies
      run: composer install --prefer-dist

    - name: Run PHPUnit tests # CI fails here!
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit --no-coverage

    - name: Install npm dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: Run Mix
      run: npm run production
```

my Laravel backend database configuration file `config/database.php`has     `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),` and

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'canie-db'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'canie-db'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'iabs_user'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'p@ssw0rd'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

I also tried adding `docker-compose up -d canie-db` to my workflow but it also doesn't work

Comment: Here is an example using postgres https://github.com/actions/example-services/blob/master/.github/workflows/postgres-service.yml.  The major issue is posgres does not define a health check so it may not be up when your script runs.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson thanks for the working example! I made a quick try adding the healthCheck in "options:" tag but no succeess. Got the same error. i must be missing something more

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I adapted my CI code to the example you shared and it magically started working. Thanks alot! But still confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is spelled out in the comments and example posted https://github.com/actions/example-services/blob/master/.github/workflows/postgres-service.yml

Why it's not working is your workflow/steps are running in a VM (ubuntu-18.04) and the VM does not know about the docker container host name of *canie-db*

One fix would be to use localhost since the ports are exposed

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
```

Or optionally, like you found using the example, run the workflow and postgres in a container. This way the host *canie-db* is known.

```
container:
  image:  node:10.16-jessie
```